# Ansible Host/Group Structure

Tags: linux, windows, automation, ansible

I need help figuring out how I should structure my hosts and groups for my use case.

Let me set the scene a little. My current setup is as follows:

*hosts*

```
[windows]
client_1 ansible_host=172.0.0.1
[linux]
client_2 ansible_host=172.0.0.2
client_3 ansible_host=172.0.0.3
```

Let's take a look at just the windows setup.

*group_vars/windows*

```
jboss_service_name: JBOSSAS7SVC
app_service_name: APPSRVC
...
```

*host_vars/client_1*

```
ansible_user: username
ansible_password: pasword
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Then my playbook looks as follows:

```
- hosts: '{{ target }}'
  name: Stop JBoss and App Services.
  remote_user: '{{ ansible_user }}'
  tasks:
  - name: Stopping JBoss Service.
    win_service:
      name: '{{ jboss_service_name }}'
      start_mode: manual
      state: stopped

  - name: Stopping App Service.
    win_service:
      name: '{{ app_service_name }}'
      start_mode: manual
      state: stopped
```

So I can run my play as follows:

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --extra-var "target=client_1"
```

Or for all windows machines:

```
ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml --extra-var "target=windows"
```

This works fine, I have this working as listed above. However, this solution is for a single server setup for my clients. Meaning jboss, the app, web and db server are all on the same physical server - in this case 172.0.0.1.

However this is not always the case. For any given client, it might be a shared or distributed setup. Meaning the jboss, app, web, db services may be on a single server, or each be on their own server.

So I've been trying to adapt this setup but I'm not sure exactly how to run my plays such that I'm executing the showdown service commands on a particular client server. I need to still be able to execute a playbook on a single client or a group - windows.

This is what I've come up with so far.

*hosts* (**removed the ansible_host=...**)

```
[windows]
client_1
[linux]
client_2
client_3
```

*group_vars/windows* (**No changes here**)

```
jboss_service_name: JBOSSAS7SVC
app_service_name: APPSRVC
...
```

*host_vars/client_1* (**moved ip addresses down to the client host_var level**)

```
ansible_user: username
ansible_password: pasword
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore

app_server: 172.0.0.1
jboss_server: app_server: 172.0.0.2
web_server: app_server: 172.0.0.3
...
```

In the above host_var file, if it was a shared setup I would just set **_server* variables to all use the same IP address.

I've created a test playbook that debug prints variables in the host_var file and group_var file, meaning it has access to all of that data.

I execute it as follows:

```
ansible-playbook -i client_1 test-playbook.yml
```

I could then pass in the group windows instead of a client host.

But what I don't understand is how to edit my old playbook to make use of these new variables, eg the call to win_service to shutdown jboss for that client should only be executed on server *host_vars/client_1.app_server*, likewise shutting down my app service should only be ran on server *app_server* for that client.

I know this is a long piece of text, so thank you for taking the time to read it.

My question is then, do I have this completely wrong? How should I structure my hosts such that I can distinguish between windows and linux hosts, can set this up by client, and be able to support a shared or distributed server setup for any given client?

Many thanks.

Comment: @jww What you are seeing in the question is a piece of Ansible code. How is dealing with code "not about programming or development"?

Answer (score 1):

Name your hosts something different, but use the same IP addresses:

```
[windows_app]
wa01 ansible_host=111.111.111.1

[windows_jboss]
wj01 ansible_host=111.111.111.1

[windows:children]
windows_app
windows_jboss
```

Define `service_name` in `group_vars/windows_app` and `group_vars/windows_jboss`.

Your playbooks should define the hosts for the specific plays:

```
- hosts: windows
  name: Stop JBoss and App Services on Windows servers
  remote_user: '{{ ansible_user }}'
  tasks:
  - name: Stopping Service.
    win_service:
      name: '{{ service_name }}'
      start_mode: manual
      state: stopped
```

Don't use `--extra-vars`, but `-l` or `--limit=` to stop one service but not the other:

```
ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml -l windows_app
```